# how to import nanomemoize in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the right syntax to import [nano-memoize](https://github.com/anywhichway/nano-memoize) in a React Typescript project? This library doesn't have type declaration file.

I am using the following in the project:

- typescript + react
- webpack
- babel + babel-loader + @babel/preset-typescript ^7.7.0

These are my tsc options

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": [ "es7", "dom" ],
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noEmit" : true
    },
```

Here are the list of errors:

1. This code builds (npm run build) but throws error in browser `Uncaught ReferenceError: nanomemoize is not defined`.

```
import "nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize";

// @ts-ignore
const myFunc = nanomemoize(...);
```

2. Code compiles. Error in Browser `Uncaught TypeError: n.n(...)(...) is not a function`

```
import nanomemoize from "nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize";

const myFunc = nanomemoize(...);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking to import it directly and use the `nanomemoize()` function in a file, install the `node_module` and then try:

```
import * as nanomemoize from 'nano-memoize'
```

Comment: You can't call a namespace import